# font awesome doesn't display well in div with custom class and row class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

Edit : This is what it shows [image: font]

I want to use font awesome using : `<span class="fa fa-user"></span>`.
When I put this code in the div with row and custom class, it doesn't work. But when the div has only row class, it works.

WORK

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

DOESN'T WORK

```
<div class="row bottom">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bottom
{
    height:auto;
    background-color:#5C772A;
    color: white;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Any Idea please ? Thanks.

Comment: Are the colors in your bottom class causing the fa icon to appear invisible?

Comment: i think your just covering the font-awesome here or the color of the font awesome is white thats why you cant see it.. can you provide some fiddle?

Comment: Try put ur code in fiddle or codepen

Comment: In fact, I can see it but it doesn't appear correctly. It show a Strange character

Comment: Can you make sure all of the font files are loading correctly in your console?

Comment: @SESN the fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/yLq5uexo/

Comment: @mhyassin yes because it works when i remove .bottom class. You can try there : https://jsfiddle.net/yLq5uexo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine I guess. Let us know what is not working?

**EDIT:**

Remove the `font-family` in the below style that you are using and it will work fine (it overrides font-awesome styles)

```
.bottom span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Another option:

Without changing any css replace span with i like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

and it will work without changing your css!

```css
.bottom
{
    height:auto;
    background-color:#5C772A;
    color: white;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row bottom">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad. Thinking that the problem whas from that class but it comes from another. Thank you.

Comment: you can do another thing without changing any css replace `span` with `i` like this: `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using this css rule:

```
.bottom span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This is overriding the `font-family` of the font awesome spans, you should remove the `font-family` rule and everything will be working fine.

Or you can use the not CSS selector to add your rule to every span inside `.bottom` but `.fa` spans:

```
.bottom span:not(.fa) {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Or you can use `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>` instead of spans for font awesome icons.

Comment: Oh How did I miss that. Thank you.